# Remove Pagging From Grapql With Client Query

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

Helllo,

How can I remove `UsePagging` some client request?

I am just want return all data some request but my query have `UsePagging` (UseSortingAttribute).

[image]

```
HotChocolate 12

.Net 6
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you have trouble to receive all of the data from one request.

`[UseSorting]` doesn't have any impact on the data that is returned, until you specify the request with [sorting parameters](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/fetching-data/sorting).

If you have problems, that not all of your data is returned in one request you should either

- delete `[UsePaging(DefaultPageSize = 150)]`
- change the page size (e.g. `[UsePaging(DefaultPageSize = 500)]`)
- use the pagination by adding fields like 'first', 'last', 'after' or 'before' to the query (e.g. `query{yourQuery(first:4) {...}}`)